# Buttons OnClick event not firing when it causes a textboxes onChange event to fire first

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a few textboxes and button to save their values on a web page. The `onchange` event of the textboxes fires some js which adds the changed text to a js array. The ok button when clicked flushes this to the database via a webservice. This works fine **except** when the `onchange` event is caused by clicking the ok button. In this scenario the onchange of the textboxes still fires but the `onClick` event of the button does not. Any ideas?

textboxes look something like:

```
<input name="ctrlJPView$tbcTabContainer$Details$JP_Details_Address2Text" type="text" value="test" 
id="ctrlJPView_tbcTabContainer_Details_JP_Details_Address2Text" onchange="addSaveDetails('Jobs###' +    document.getElementById('ctrlJPView_tbcTabContainer_Details_JP_Details_Address2Text').value + ');" style="font-size:8pt;Left:110px;Top:29px;Width:420px;Height:13px;Position:absolute;" />
```

My save button:

```
<input type="button" name="ctrlJPView$btnOk" value="OK" onclick="saveAmendments();refreshJobGrids();return false;__doPostBack('ctrlJPView$btnOk','')" id="ctrlJPView_btnOk" class="ControlText" style="width:60px;" />
```

UPDATE: I guess this comes down to one of two things.

1. Something is happening before the `onClick` of the button gets called to surpress that call such as an inadvertent `return false;` or
2. the `onClick` event isn't firing at all.

Now I've remembered out everything actually inside the functions that are being called beforehand but the problem persists, but if I remove the call altogether it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is the `__doPostBack` function the one failing to execute? in this case, the `return false` is the obvious problem - once you return, no more code gets executed.

on a more pedantic note, you should really stop using onBlah handlers in your html, and instead use a modern javascript library that provides event observers. i recommend [jquery](http://docs.jquery.com/Events)  but [extjs](http://www.extjs.com/learn/Manual:Intro:Event_Handling) or [prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/event/observe)  would also work and make life much easier for you in a thousand other ways.

Comment: The __doPostBack is being appended because in my .net code i've set the inputs' useSubmitBehavior to false. The function which looks after the saving is the saveAmendments function which should have excuted before return false. You would think that possible something is failing in the textboxes onchange event but from debugging it doesn't appear so. I've scaled back to function todo nothing essentially.